# Get the Last Modifying User of a file from the SharePoint web API

Tags: sharepoint-online, python

I am using python and want to make a simple request to get the last modifying user from the list of items in a document library. This is my code:

```
import sharepy

s = sharepy.connect("company.sharepoint.com", username='eamil@company.onmicrosoft.com', password='password')

r = s.get(spo_site + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + spo_library + "')/items?$select=[**What Do I Put Here**]&$Top=1")
```

Basically just need to know what to put in the bold to get the last modifying user.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=**Editor? ModifiedBy? LastUser?**&$Top=1
```

I thought Editor was a valid field, but when I use it, I get this error message:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The query to field 'Editor' is not valid. The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains Editor.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Answer (score 1):

EditorId will return the Site Collection level ID of the user. You can then query to get user info:

```
https://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_api/web/siteusers/getbyid(9)?$select=Title,LoginName,Id
```